# Firebase Angularjs prevent user to display app pages if user not verified yet

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angular-ui-router, firebase-authentication

For an angularjs web project using firebase backend, registered users shouldn't be able to display application pages if they are not verified yet. I use that code below at each page controller:

```
function config($stateProvider)
{
  .state('app.pages_profile', {
      url      : '/pages/profile',
      views    : {
         'content@app': {
              templateUrl: 'app/main/pages/profile/profile.html',
              controller : 'ProfileController as vm'
         }
      },
      resolve  : {
         "currentAuth": ["Auth", function(Auth) {
         return Auth.$requireSignIn();
         }]
      }
  })
}
```

At IndexController I aimed to listen auth state changes and if user is not verified yet redirect to verification warning page.

```
(function ()
{
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('xyz')
        .controller('IndexController', IndexController);

    function IndexController(Auth, $state)
    {
        var vm = this;

        Auth.$onAuthStateChanged(function(firebaseUser) {
            if(firebaseUser)
            {     
                if (firebaseUser.emailVerified==false) {
                    $state.go ("app.pages_auth_verification");
                } 
            }
        });
    }
})();
```

In fact it works the way I want it ( it redirects as I want) but on console log it shows also an error:

> *angular.js:14525 Error: transition superseded
>       at $StateProvider.$get (angular-ui-router.js:2909)
>       at Object.invoke (angular.js:5003)
>       at angular.js:4795
>       at Object.getService [as get] (angular.js:4944)
>       at angular-ui-router.js:3696
>       at Object.invoke (angular.js:5003)
>       at angular.js:4805
>       at forEach (angular.js:403)
>       at createInjector (angular.js:4805)
>       at doBootstrap (angular.js:1914) "Possibly unhandled rejection: {}*

The way I use is right? And/or is there a better way to control and prevent user if not verified.

Comment: According to comments here - https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/3246 - try updating angular and ui-router.

Comment: yes. upgrading angular-ui-router to version: 0.4.2 fixed the problem. I use angular: 1.6.4 @camden_kid

Comment: Cool. You may want to add an answer with your solution and that github link.